# Conditionally highlight data in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having some trouble conditionally plot pandas dataframe.

Let's say we have a 4 * 4 dataframe, `columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`, 
`indexes=[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Let's say we do a `df.plot.bar()`. And for the data in each row, I want to highlight the bars if data in `column C >= column A + column B`. Do the same for data in `Column D`.

The end result should highlight the bars that satisfy the above requirement in red, the rest are left white.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 4, 2],
        [4, 3, 5, 9],
        [3, 1, 0, 1],
        [2, 6, 9, 2]
    ], columns=list('ABCD'))

condAB = pd.DataFrame(False, df.index, ['A', 'B'])
condCD = df[['C', 'D']].ge(df[['A', 'B']].sum(1), 0)
cond = pd.concat([condAB, condCD], axis=1).stack().tolist()
colors = np.where(cond, 'red', 'white')

df.plot.bar(color=colors, legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. I think your method works, but I noticed that the number 5 in the 2nd row was also highlighted. Not sure why that happens but thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexMeow Yeah, that is weird.  I'll look into it when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your time.